# Rayleigh law contradicting tyndall effect

Tags: particle-physics, visible-light, scattering, wavelength

Sir, we have been taught that according to Rayleigh, the amount of scattering of light is inversely proportional to the fourth power of its wavelength and this law only occurs when the size of a particle is much smaller than the wavelength of the incident light. But as we observe in the Tyndall effect, homogeneous mixtures (small particles) do not scatter light but colloidal and heterogeneous mixtures do. Isn't it contradictory?
Please help me out. Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: see the comparison of the two  here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect#Comparison_with_Rayleigh_scattering

Answer (score 0):

There is a condition for Rayleigh scattering, I.e. size of scatterer must be less than or equal to wavelength of light to be scattered,true solution does not fulfil this condition ( size less than 1 nm) but colloidal and suspension have comparable size 1 to 1000 nm and greater than 1000nm respectively.thats why they do scattering and Rayleigh shattering law can be applicable ie blue colour ( wavelength 400nm) scattered more than red color ( wavelength 700nm)

You can apply Rayleigh scattering law only conditionally...Which is stated above. There is no contradiction.Thats why this type of question had not been asked ever.Make you more clear in Rayleigh Law

Comment: Sir as you said That Red colour wavelength is 700 and blue colour wavelength is 400nm But sir as we know That The size of suspension is greater than 1000 nm so how does it scatters light as the size of particles must be smaller